# Firebase Javascript: Callback function does not return anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a chatting application that allows users to create rooms to discuss specific topics. An issue that I am having is that when users create rooms with the same names, data gets overridden.

I tried going through each individual room, and checking if the room inputted matches the room name that the user created. The problem with this, is that I can only get data asynchronously. I tried to implement a callback function to update the variable, but this doesn't seem to work, because my alert command is not functioning.

**Javascript / JQuery**:

```
 var roomName = $.trim(document.getElementById("roomname").value.toLowerCase());

 var duplicate = function(roomname) {
  var found = false;
  roomsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    if (found == roomname) {
      found = true;
    }
  });
 }

 duplicate(roomName, function(found) {
  alert(found); // State whether it's a duplicate room or not.
 });
```

**Database Structure**:

```
rooms
    -all
    -algorithms
    -boxing
    -javascript
    -money
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite some small mistakes in your code. This should work better:

```
var roomName = $.trim(document.getElementById("roomname").value.toLowerCase());

var duplicate = function(roomname, callback) {
  var found = false;
  roomsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.key == roomname) {
      found = true;
      callback(snapshot.val())
    }
  });
}

duplicate(roomName, function(found) {
  alert(found); // State whether it's a duplicate room or not.
});
```

The changes:

- You pass a callback into `duplicate(roomName, function(found) {`... But your implementation of `duplicate` never declares or uses that callback. I added a parameter for the callback and then invoke it when the room is found.
- You compare the boolean `found` with the string `roomname` you get from the text element. That comparison will never be true. More likely you want to compare the value from the database with `roomname`. My code does that, although I am not certain if `snapshot.key` is correct for your data structure.

But this code is still wasteful. You don't need to listen for all rooms to know if a specific one exists. You just need to check for that one. This can be done with a simple read of just the one location:

```
var duplicate = function(roomname, callback) {
  var found = false;
  roomsRef.child(roomname).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
      found = true;
      callback(snapshot.val())
    }
  });
}
```